# How to find the critical values of chi-square distribution in python?

Tags: python, statistics

I want to calculate the interval estimate of the population standard deviation, for this i need the chi-square critical values for the lower and upper bound. The formula to calculate is this -

[image: formula]

To calculate it, i did this -

```
# variance
var = halloween['Dollars Spent'].var()
# (n-1) degrees of freedom
deg_fred = (halloween.shape[0] - 1)
lower_bound = np.sqrt((deg_fred*var)/ 27.488)
upper_bound = np.sqrt((deg_fred*var)/ 6.262)
(lower_bound, upper_bound)
(17.37, 36.40)
```

The critical values of chi-square distribution for the lower and upper bound are `27.488` and `6.262`. I find these values using the chi-square distribution table. How can i calculate these values in python rather than calculating it from a table which doesn't give us exact values all the time and it is not helpful if i want to write a function to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Using **isf()** method

```
import scipy as sp
sp.stats.chi2.isf(0.1, 20, loc=0, scale=1) # P=10%, df=20
# donne 28.412... as in books table
```